# Translation of "I'm looking forward to..."

Tags: translation, verb, sentence-structure, phrase-request, verb-usage

I'm writing a short essay and I wonder about how I could express "I'm looking forward to...".
I found out that I should use the verb "sich auf etw. freuen". So I tried to write this sentence like this:

> Ich freue mich auf Weihnachten, wenn ich zu Hause sein werde.

What i tried to express is "I'm looking forward to Christmas, when I will finally be back home".

Is it correct?

Comment: Another question about the same thing. I am trying now to express this: "I am so looking forward to see each other again".

Would this be correct? 
"Ich freue mich auf, wenn wir uns noch einmal wiedersehen können"

Comment: "freuen auf" needs an object: "Ich freue mich *darauf*, wenn...

Comment: So this then should be correct: "Ich freue mich darauf, wenn wir uns noch einmal wiedersehen können"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion is correct. "Sich auf etwas freuen" is often used in daily language.

Note that the second part of your sentence does not yet contain "finally", so you could write "Ich freue mich auf Weihnachten, wenn ich endlich wieder zu Hause sein werde."

Comment: The sentence is a little weird though and can be easily understood as "I will look forward to x-mas only once I'm home (which I'm not yet)" It doesn't sound idiomatic to me.

Comment: How should I express it then what I actually mean?

What i tried to express is "I'm looking forward to Christmas, when I will finally be back home".